# Viewing the documents on per weekday classification?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

I have data like this in my ES 2.4.0:

```
{"text": "are","created_at": "2017-01-29T05:30:36.000Z"}
{"text": "hi","created_at": "2017-01-28T18:30:36.000Z"}
{"text": "you","created_at": "2017-01-31T09:30:36.000Z"} 
{"text": "how","created_at": "2017-01-28T11:30:36.000Z"}
{"text": "hello","created_at": "2017-01-30T23:30:36.000Z"}
```

For viewing documents on per weekday classification i used the below groovy script:

```
Date date = new Date(doc[date_field].value); date.format(format);
```

In my output it is showing like these :

```
 "aggregations": {
    "byDays": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "Sunday",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Tuesday",
          "doc_count": 2
        },
        {
          "key": "Saturday",
          "doc_count": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But my input dates will come on following days

```
   {"text": "are","created_at": "2017-01-29T05:30:36.000Z"} --sunday
    {"text": "hi","created_at": "2017-01-28T18:30:36.000Z"}--saturday
    {"text": "you","created_at": "2017-01-31T09:30:36.000Z"} --tuesday
    {"text": "how","created_at": "2017-01-28T11:30:36.000Z"}--sunday
    {"text": "hello","created_at": "2017-01-30T23:30:36.000Z"}--monday
```

Do i need to change the timezone to get the accurate days?

Comment: Have you tried to change the time zone in your script? What happens?

Comment: NO,i didnt tried changing the timezone in my groovy script.Can you say how to do it?

Comment: When i tried with inline script by giving `date.dayOfWeek().getAsText()` it is working fine but if i am using stored script it is not showing accurate days..

Comment: Val.. Can you help me in solving this question?