# Can i able to run both the inline script and stored script in one query in ES?

Tags: elasticsearch, groovy

ES 2.4.0
I tried to do aggregations with both the inline script and stored script. But when i executed the code it is showing error..

```
{
      "size": 0,
      "aggregations": {
        "dayOfWeek": {
          "terms": {
            "script": "doc['created_at'].date.dayOfWeek().getAsText()"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "byHours": {
              "terms": {
                "order": {
                  "_term": "asc"
                },
                "script": "test",
                "params": {
                  "date_field": "created_at",
                  "format": "HH"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

When i executed the above code, i am getting error like these

```
{
  "took": 106,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 4,
    "failures": [
      {
        "shard": 1,
        "index": "test",
        "node": "PHgQhqS8T6KORwsJ5ChzHg",
        "reason": {
          "type": "script_exception",
          "reason": "failed to run inline script [test] using lang [groovy]",
          "caused_by": {
            "type": "missing_property_exception",
            "reason": "No such property: test for class: a94a8fe5ccb19ba61c4c0873d391e987982fbbd3"
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference your script file like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "dayOfWeek": {
      "terms": {
        "script": "doc['created_at'].date.dayOfWeek().getAsText()"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "byHours": {
          "terms": {
            "order": {
              "_term": "asc"
            },
            "script": {                   <--- modify this section
              "file": "test",
              "params": {
                 "date_field": "created_at",
                 "format": "HH"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks val..got it. Can you help me in solving this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41912800/viewing-the-documents-on-per-weekday-classification?noredirect=1#comment71017184_41912800